# Can't extract nodejs source file with tar

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, tar

I recently tried to install nodejs on Ubuntu Natty on my WMWare Workstation. I got the source file from [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.tar.gz). And I'm following the instructions for doing that [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-linux.html)

However, when I try to extract the dowloaded archive I get an error. I enter this `tar -zxvf node-v0.6.6.tar.gz` and I get the following at the end of the operation.

```
node-v0.6.6/benchmark/arrays/zero_int.js
tar: node-v0.6.6/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/md4.c: Cannot create symlink to `../crypto/md4/md4.c': Operation not supported
tar: node-v0.6.6/tools/run-valgrind.py: Cannot create symlink to `../deps/v8/tools/run-valgrind.py': Operation not supported
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I am logged in as root. Not sure why I get this.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an unverified guess, but is it possible you are trying to extract it on a filesystem that doesn't support symlinks?

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you mean?! I created a symlink earlier in the day for a php installation I did.

Comment: What I meant was that for example maybe you were trying to extract it inside a shared folder from the VMware host or something, which may not have support for symlinks, but if you've managed to create a symlink on the same filesystem already, then my assumption (and answer) is incorrect. I'm afraid that I have no idea what else could cause this, sorry :/

Comment: Thanks so much, I sorted out the issue with your guidance. That was actually what I was doing without knowing it i.e. I had them on a shared folder from the host and I was trying to extract it directly from there. I simply copied the folders to a Linux native directory and it works ok now. Cheers.